# Authlogic - how to check if a user is logged out

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timeout, authlogic

This is my setup:

user.rb

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.logged_in_timeout(1.minutes)
  end
```

user_session.rb

```
  def to_key
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end
  self.logout_on_timeout = true
```

application_controller.rb

```
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

  private
    def current_user_session
      logger.debug "ApplicationController::current_user_session"
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      logger.debug "ApplicationController::current_user"
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
    end

    def require_user
      logger.debug "ApplicationController::require_user"
      unless current_user
        #store_location
        flash[:warning] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
        #redirect_to new_user_session_url
        redirect_to root_url
        return false
      end
    end

    def require_no_user
      logger.debug "ApplicationController::require_no_user"
      if current_user
        #store_location
        flash[:warning] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
        redirect_to account_url
        return false
      end
    end
```

But when I load my page, I will get the error

```
undefined method `logged_out?' for #<User:0x00000103ee8348>
```

I try to read the official GitHub page of Authlogic, but I still don't know, what I miss... Could anyone give me a tip for fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, and it boiled down to the fact I didn't have all of the necessary columns in my User model.

My original User model (from `db/schema.rb`) was pretty minimalistic:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "perm",               :default => "employee"
end
```

However, I added the column `t.datetime :last_requested_at` to my model, as well as a few others that may or may not be needed. My final User model looks like:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "perm",               :default => "employee"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "login_count",        :default => 0,          :null => false
    t.integer  "failed_login_count", :default => 0,          :null => false
    t.datetime "last_request_at"
    t.datetime "current_login_at"
    t.datetime "last_login_at"
    t.string   "current_login_ip"
    t.string   "last_login_ip"
end
```

After adding in the other columns, I no longer get the `undefined method 'logged_out?'...` error.

Good luck!

(reference/more info: http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2009/05/authlogic-and-openid-on-rails/ -- search in the page for `logged_out?`, the explanation was about 3/4 of the way down the post.)

Comment: To solve undefined method 'logged_out', only "last_request_at" is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if a user is logged out, you can do:

```
if current_user_session
  ...
```

This condition will return `true` if the user is logged in (there is a session), and `false` if they are logged out (the session is `nil`).

As for the error message, `undefined method 'logged_out?' for #<User:0x00000103ee8348>` means that you haven't defined a method called `logged_out?`, so it doesn't know what you mean.

Authlogic doesn't define a `logged_out?` method for the `User` model, and neither have you, so there's nothing to call. The reason is that the state of either being "logged in" or being "logged out" doesn't have anything to do with the `User` model, but instead is a property of whether or not a given user has an active `UserSession` record.